# python pyparrot image processing question

Tags: python

I'm trying to build code that wants to fly a drone with a camera with demoMamboVisionGUI.py below. When the code is executed, the camera screen comes up and press the button to start the flight. The code above displays four cam screens and detects a straight line while detecting a specified color value, blue (BGR2HSV). Using these two codes, the camera recognizes the blue straight line and flies forward little by little, and turns left and right at a certain angle, recognizes the bottom of the specified color (red), lands, and starts flying with another button. I want to make a code that recognizes green and lands. I would appreciate it if you could throw a simple hint.

## [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0oYo.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def im_trim(img):
    x = 160
    y = 50
    w = 280
    h = 180
    img_trim = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    return img_trim

def go():
    minimum = 9999;
    min_theta=0;
    try:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    except:
        return
    while True:
        ret, P = cap.read()

        img1 = P
        cv2.imshow('asdf',img1)
        img_HSV = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        img_h, img_s, img_v = cv2.split(img_HSV)
        cv2.imshow("HSV", img_HSV)
        lower_b = np.array([100, 80, 100])
        upper_b = np.array([120, 255, 255])
        blue = cv2.inRange(img_HSV, lower_b, upper_b)
        cv2.imshow('root',blue)
        edges = cv2.Canny(blue, 50, 150, apertureSize =3)
        lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi/180, threshold = 100)
        if lines is not None:
             for line in lines:
                 r, theta = line[0]
                 #if (r<minimum and r>0) and (np.rad2deg(theta)>-90 and np.rad2deg(theta)<90):
                     #minimum = r
                     #min_theta = theta

                 #if (r > 0 and r < 250) and (np.rad2deg(theta) > 170 or np.rad2deg(theta) < 10):

                  #       self.drone_object.fly_direct(pitch=0, roll=-7, yaw=0, vertical_movement=0,
                   #                                   duration=1)
                         #print("right")



                 #elif (r > 400 and r < 650) and (np.rad2deg(theta) > 170 or np.rad2deg(theta) < 10):

                  #       self.drone_object.fly_direct(pitch=0, roll=7, yaw=0, vertical_movement=0,
                   #                                   duration=1)



                 print(r, np.rad2deg(theta))
                 #이하 if문을 while 문을 통해 반복하여 길 경로를 직진경로로 만든 이후 진행
                 #if(np.rad2deg(min_theta)>=몇도이상 or 이하):
                 # 이하 -> 왼쪽턴, 이상 -> 오른쪽턴, 사이 -> 직진
                 a = np.cos(theta)
                 b = np.sin(theta)
                 x0 = a * r
                 y0 = b * r
                 x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
                 y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * a)
                 x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
                 y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * a)
                 cv2.line(img1, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0), 3)

        cv2.imshow('hough',img1)
        k = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if k == 27:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    go()
    print("??")
```

================================================================================================

```
"""
Demo of the Bebop vision using DroneVisionGUI that relies on libVLC.  It is a different
multi-threaded approach than DroneVision

Author: Amy McGovern
"""
from pyparrot.Minidrone import Mambo
from pyparrot.DroneVisionGUI import DroneVisionGUI
import cv2


# set this to true if you want to fly for the demo
testFlying = True

class UserVision:
    def __init__(self, vision):
        self.index = 0
        self.vision = vision

    def save_pictures(self, args):
        # print("in save pictures on image %d " % self.index)

        img = self.vision.get_latest_valid_picture()

        if (img is not None):
            filename = "test_image_%06d.png" % self.index
            # uncomment this if you want to write out images every time you get a new one
            #cv2.imwrite(filename, img)
            self.index +=1
            #print(self.index)


def demo_mambo_user_vision_function(mamboVision, args):
    """
    Demo the user code to run with the run button for a mambo

    :param args:
    :return:
    """
    mambo = args[0]

    if (testFlying):
        print("taking off!")
        mambo.safe_takeoff(5)

        if (mambo.sensors.flying_state != "emergency"):
            print("flying state is %s" % mambo.sensors.flying_state)
            print("Flying direct: going up")
            mambo.fly_direct(roll=0, pitch=0, yaw=0, vertical_movement=15, duration=2)

            print("flip left")
            print("flying state is %s" % mambo.sensors.flying_state)
            success = mambo.flip(direction="left")
            print("mambo flip result %s" % success)
            mambo.smart_sleep(5)

        print("landing")
        print("flying state is %s" % mambo.sensors.flying_state)
        mambo.safe_land(5)
    else:
        print("Sleeeping for 15 seconds - move the mambo around")
        mambo.smart_sleep(15)

    # done doing vision demo
    print("Ending the sleep and vision")
    mamboVision.close_video()

    mambo.smart_sleep(5)

    print("disconnecting")
    mambo.disconnect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # you will need to change this to the address of YOUR mambo
    mamboAddr = "B0:FC:36:F4:37:F9"

    # make my mambo object
    # remember to set True/False for the wifi depending on if you are using the wifi or the BLE to connect
    mambo = Mambo(mamboAddr, use_wifi=True)
    print("trying to connect to mambo now")
    success = mambo.connect(num_retries=3)
    print("connected: %s" % success)

    if (success):
        # get the state information
        print("sleeping")
        mambo.smart_sleep(1)
        mambo.ask_for_state_update()
        mambo.smart_sleep(1)

        print("Preparing to open vision")
        mamboVision = DroneVisionGUI(mambo, is_bebop=False, buffer_size=200,
                                     user_code_to_run=demo_mambo_user_vision_function, user_args=(mambo, ))
        userVision = UserVision(mamboVision)
        mamboVision.set_user_callback_function(userVision.save_pictures, user_callback_args=None)
        mamboVision.open_video()
```

==========================================================================